# Why is there no reference request tag here?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, specific-question

i'm an active user of math.stackexchange and occasional user of stackoverflow. I noticed a question on our forum which seemed better asked here

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367851/reference-for-dynamic-arrays?noredirect=1#comment2783878_1367851

But according to the OP, they couldn't find a reference-request tag here on stackoverflow, which I thought was odd, considering at least at math.se it's a pretty frequently used tag for exchanging information.

Are there any plans to create it? Or was it discussed and a clear reason for avoiding it found?

Comment: Asking for external resources such as documentation is specifically off-topic here. In our experience, such requests attract a significant amount of spam instead.

Comment: Straight off-topic

Comment: The equivalent of "This tag is for questions seeking external references (books, articles, etc.) about a particular subject. Please do not use this as the only tag for a question" is exactly the same as a close reason on SO: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Ah, It seems I was not aware that such was the policy here. Is it due to the volume of users that such questions become problematic? Because I have seen it done successfully on other sites, but they are, at the end of the day much smaller, and I guess there is more consensus between the community over what resource to use, vs. what not to use.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas I imagine that for math (and other sites) resources are generally more narrowly (or perhaps strictly) defined - academic / published / recognisable papers etc... While for SO - it could be a language spec, an implementation of a spec, a how-to guide (from various websites), blogs (again from various websites), a link to github that's related (or sometimes not), or believe it or not "hey - this guy helped me with his youtube video walkthrough" links as well...