# Is there a tag meaning I am looking for an authoritative reference?

Tags: support, tags

There is a bounty reason:

> Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.

Is there any tag I can flag my question with to convey such message?

Tag `reference` is dedicated for a programming concept.

[EDIT]

It is not a duplicate of [Why is there no reference request tag here?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299712/why-is-there-no-reference-request-tag-here) : "OP asks to support answers with a credible source they are based on." is different to "What may be a reference to the fact OP already knows?"

Comment: Nope, and there shouldn't be, since that's a meta tag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: No.  That bounty reason is the can't-think-of-anything-else choice.  Everybody expects a credible answer and contributors are always assumed to provide one.  A bounty is only needed if existing answers don't explain the solution well enough for the OP to understand.

Comment: @HansPassant I disagree. The name of the reason is "Authoritative reference needed". There is a lot of answers which are not explicitly backed by a reference to any source.

Comment: Just demand one in the question body.  Keeping in mind that the odds you'll get such an answer are low, product owners in general don't post to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) tag when you're asking about intricacies of official specifications rather than a particular implementation.

Since this kind of meaning has a potential to be abused as a [meta-tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) as others noted, **stick to its description letter strictly to avoid overuse**, as that would lead to it being seen as problematic and removed.

For questions not involving specification intricacies, **just use the general tag for the language/environment, without more specific tags** specifying the particular flavor.

Comment: The tag looks exactly as what is called a "meta-tag" for me as it is useless as the only tag (without a language tag etc.).

Comment: @abukaj propose burnination and we'll see.

Comment: @abukaj also note [tag:language-agnostic] and [tag:algorithm].

Comment: @abukaj and tags for families of products, like [tag:confluent-kafka].

Comment: As I like meta-tags, I'd rather not risk such proposal.

Answer (score 1):

No, we don't use tags for that purpose. See the blog post linked above.

As mentioned, just ask for a reference in your question text and feel free to downvote any answers that proceed to ignore your request.